# Using ASP.NET MVC3 AntiForgery token from CCW

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0

I have some legacy application that are currently posting basic information to a MVC3 form. I would like to seperate that out to a GET and pass the values in the querystring. Easy enough. However, I would like to add an anti-forgery token to the request. First of all, does this seem like a good option? Second, are there any examples of implementing such functionality from a non-MVC3 module to an MVC3 form?

My other alternative would be to encrypt the querystring.

Comment: If your _new GET_ operations are going to perform changes in your application (which makes sense since they used to be POST) you will be violating the HTTP-GET specification defined in W3C, which say that GET requests must be safe and read-only. If you do not follow this approach...you'll find soon or later inconsistencies in your application if Google's crawlers index your site

Comment: I agree with Jupaol here, it violates http spec. Why not just keep as a post request in MVC? Your non-mvc3 module however won't be able to have an appropriate antiforgerytoken that mVC3 uses so you'll be stuck trying to figure out something else. If no state is being changed, then you don't need anti forgery, but simply auth.

Comment: They are not performing any modifications which is why we want to move the POST to a get. The POST was used to hide the values being passed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Anti-Forgery Token as implemented by ASP.NET is meant as a mechanism to prevent CSRF (that corss-site-request-forgery) and does only work with HTTP `POST`.

Since you are implementing a `GET` based "API" this Token won't work (BEWARE of limits for example on the length of a querystring).

I am not sure what exactly your goal is... Depending on your goal the solution is encrypting or signing the querystring or both.

Comment: I believe you are correct. I am going to go the route of encrypting the querystring. Even though there are a number of posts saying not to, it seems like my best solution. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can every post you want to this mvc3 action. You only have to make sure your postdata matches the serverside object. And Yes you have to use an antiforgery token for safety.

in javascript you can make for example a post like this with jQuery. As you can see I don't use the form, but just some javascript code. Mvc can perfectly handle this.

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: urlToYourMvcAction,
    data: {
        name: 'John Doe',
        age: 25
    }, 
    success: successCalback,
    error: errorCallback);

public class Person
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; ;set }
    public int Age { get; set; }
}

public class PersonController : Controller
{
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Add(Person person)
    {
          //Your code
    }
}
```

You can easily make the same post request with the c# WebClient object in your legacy application. You can use fiddler or the developer tools to inspect the request and pass in the correct parameters needed to make the post.

Oh and using a get request can give you trouble when the requests are getting bigger. Posts are ment to sent data to the server. Gets are meant for getting data from the server.